# How can i add two matrices that have been shifted in coordinates

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I work on matlab and I have a question.

I have two matrices :

```
x1 = [NaN  -2    -1    0    1    2;
     1    0.21  0.15 0.34 0.11 0.32;
     2    0.14  0.10 0.16 0.31 0.11];

x2 = [NaN  -2    -1    0    1    2;
     1    0.12  0.09 0.34 0.41 0.22;
     2    0.54  0.30 0.18 0.11 0.74];
```

First row is the coordinates in X for the data.
I shift x1's first row by -0.63 and x2's first row by +0.63 which gives:

```
New_x1 = [NaN -2.63 -1.63 -0.63 0.37 1.37;
           1   0.21  0.15  0.34 0.11 0.32;
           2   0.14  0.10  0.16 0.31 0.11];

New_x2 = [NaN -1.37 -0.37 0.63 1.63 2.63;
           1   0.12  0.09 0.34 0.41 0.22;
           2   0.54  0.30 0.18 0.11 0.74];
```

I now want to add New_x1 & New_x2 **following their coordinates**, but now that I have shifted them in opposite directions, their coordinates (first row) are not "lined up" anymore. So I can't add them properly.

For exemple, New_x1: i know the value of the point -2.63, but for New_x2 i know the value of -1.37 but not -2.63.

How can I use interpolation on New_x1 and New_x2 to expand the matrices and get coordinates (first row) in common so that I can add them?

Thanks

Comment: Just find a common set of `x` points, and reinterpolate each matrix using the solution of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61746455/3460361). You will then have 2 matrices with similar `x` values, and you can simply add them.

Comment: @Hoki Hi, what do you mean by finding a common set of x points? x values are equally spaced by 1, but in my previous question taking for exemple the x point -2 makes the interpolated matrix unequally spaced: -2.63, 2, -1.63.

Comment: If you want to have the same aligned `x` values in both matrices you just need to merge `x1` and `x2` into one global `x_new`. somthing like `x_new=sort([x1(1,2:end),x2(1,2:end)])`, then reinterpolate both matrices on this new `xn` vector (using the same method than in your previous question).

Comment: I feel like you could benefit from reading about how indexing is done in Matlab. Have a read at [Matrix Indexing in MATLAB](https://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Comment: Thank you very much i'll read this and follow your advices !